# Laravel queue not honouring job specific timeout

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

According to the Laravel docs I should be able to specify a job specific timeout:

> If the timeout is specified on the job, it will take precedence over any timeout specified on the command line [...]

So, when I run `artisan queue:listen` without the `--timeout` option and I define the timeout inside the job (like Laravel tells me to):

```
public $timeout = 600;
```

I expect the timeout of that specific job to be 600 seconds. Unfortunately, I still get a `ProcessTimedOutException`. A custom timeout only works when I run the queue with `--timeout=600`.

I'm using Laravel 6 with PHP 7.4.  As recommended by Laravel I've also enabled the `pcntl` PHP extension. For the queue I use the `database` driver with the following config:

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 90,
]
```

Comment: What are the configuration settings for the queue in queue.php file?

Comment: What happen if you change `retry_after` to `610`?

Comment: The answer is in the official documentation of the Laravel for [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts), right at the beginning of the link. --timeout for command line is there as well.

Comment: I want to set the timeout in the job class, not the command line. This should be possible according to the last few paragraphs of [this](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout) section. Setting the timeout in the command line will set it for all jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31226) because I couldn't get this to work. However, it seems like the timeout specified inside the job class only takes precedence over the timeout specified in the command line when running the queue with `queue:work`.

I've tested this and can confirm that it works with `queue:work`. According to a commenter on my bug report it doesn't work with `queue:listen` because:

> `queue:listen` runs several processes while `queue:work` is a single process. `queue:listen` sets a timeout for the process it runs so we don't leave ghost processes running on the machine in case the master process was killed for some reason.